# Error downloading sharepoint 2007 audit logs

Tags: sharepoint, report, audit, sitecollection

I extended the sharepoint 2007  webapp (uses SSL underneath )  to use extranet zone and also imported the Self signed certificate in IIS with the help of IIS tools for the webapp site.  I also  have Full control in webapp user policy to all Zones but when downloading the audit logs from site collection URLs it gives me exception saying "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".  We use web service for fetching the audit logs by installing it as farm based solution and have a .Net client which contacts the web service. However, I am able to see the audit log report using the sharepoint audit  report generated using the Sharepoint Web interface through "Site Settings".   Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Paresh,

Are you attempting to audit the activity happening in SharePoint?  i.e. views, deletes, permission changes, etc...

If you are, I suggest you take a look at logbinder.com.  The LOGbinder SP product does exactly that.

Comment: Do you have any affiliation with the company that makes it?